# Merge Sorting a String Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am attempting to program an array sorting and searching program that will be handling 600 items within a string array.The data which is to be sorted looks as such:

> 2017  |  25  |  January     |  9994750  |  27.640  |  36.800  |  DODECANESE ISLANDS, GREECE     |  1485307173  |  01:19:33  |  4.000  |

I have been attempting to implement a merge sort to sort this data. However, I am unable to figure out how to convert a merge sort program designed for an int array into one designed for sorting a string array. Could anyone explain how I could do this?

Though this can be done via the use of existing built in functions I have been attempting this in preparation for university courseworks next years and so I am having to program the Merge sort from scratch and not use the built in functions.

Side note: I must note that I am aware that in its current form the program could not sort months naturally even with the merge sort but that is something I already have a work round for once I can get the merge sort operating as intended.

The current merge sort program:

```
        static public void MainMerge(string[] numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[25];
        int i, eol, num, pos;

        eol = (mid - 1);
        pos = left;
        num = (right - left + 1);

        while ((left <= eol) && (mid <= right))
        {
            if (numbers[left].CompareTo(numbers[mid]))
                temp[pos++] = numbers[left++];
            else
                temp[pos++] = numbers[mid++];
        }

        while (left <= eol)
            temp[pos++] = numbers[left++];

        while (mid <= right)
            temp[pos++] = numbers[mid++];

        for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            numbers[right] = temp[right];
            right--;
        }
    }

    static public void SortMerge(string[] numbers, int left, int right)
    {
        int mid;

        if (right > left)
        {
            mid = (right + left) / 2;
            SortMerge(numbers, left, mid);
            SortMerge(numbers, (mid + 1), right);

            MainMerge(numbers, left, (mid + 1), right);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trying to repurpose code is often more work than it's worth. It seems like a simple enough task that you would be better off starting from scratch.

Comment: @coinbird what?  This is very straightforward using generics.  There is no reason to "start from scratch"

Comment: You should implement the sort using generics that implement IComparable. `public void MergeSort<T>(this T[] elements) where T : IComparable { }`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `Array.Sort(array);` instead of implementing your own sorting?

Comment: Though it is possible to just use generics since I'm doing this to try to get better at coding in general I am trying to do it from scratch.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad this is likely an educational exercise.

Comment: @GiggyLapisar getting better at coding would imply you're learning to do things the *right* way.  Using generics would be the right way, here.  Duplicating your code and replacing `string` with `int` will work, but its a terrible solution.

Comment: @Amy makes sense, I had guessed it was not educational because the example string array was odd and had a requirement that seemed too specific to be anything but a business requirement, "handling 600 items within a string array".

Comment: Using generics would be more of a challenge than just translating from int to string. If you understand how to do this with generics then you understand how to do it for all data types you could come up with.

Comment: @Amy It is indeed an educational exercise. Apologies I did not make that clear. The idea was taking on an old university task I had been looking at in preparation for that sort of coursework. The task in question required the algorithm be done from scratch as would be expected at that level, hence why I have not been using the built in functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow your algorithm to operate on different types, we use C# Generics.  I made the following changes to your code:

- Renamed the `numbers` parameter to `values`, to better fit the other changes
- Changed the data type of the array from `string` to `T`
- Added a type constraint, so `T` is required to be comparable to other `T`
- Changed the type of the `temp` array to `T` as well.
- You're already using `CompareTo` to do your comparison, so no other code changes are needed **edit: actually, `IComparable.CompareTo` has a different return value than `string.CompareTo`, so a small adjustment will need to be made**.

I used `IComparable<T>` instead of `IComparable`.  Both should work equally well for your purposes.

Code follows:

```
static public void MainMerge<T>(T[] values, int left, int mid, int right) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T[] temp = new T[25];
    int i, eol, num, pos;

    eol = (mid - 1);
    pos = left;
    num = (right - left + 1);

    while ((left <= eol) && (mid <= right))
    {
        if (values[left].CompareTo(values[mid]))
            temp[pos++] = values[left++];
        else
            temp[pos++] = values[mid++];
    }

    while (left <= eol)
        temp[pos++] = values[left++];

    while (mid <= right)
        temp[pos++] = values[mid++];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        values[right] = temp[right];
        right--;
    }
}

static public void SortMerge<T>(T[] values, int left, int right) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int mid;

    if (right > left)
    {
        mid = (right + left) / 2;
        SortMerge(values, left, mid);
        SortMerge(values, (mid + 1), right);

        MainMerge(values, left, (mid + 1), right);
    }
}
```

You can then call this on an array of any type that is comparable to itself.  `int` and `string` should both work just fine.

Comment: Seems like it should work. For some reason though the .CompareTo part throws a "Cannot implicity convert _int_ to _bool_" error.

Comment: @GiggyLapisar okay, `CompareTo` returns `0` if the items are equal, -1 if the left item sorts first, or 1 if the right item sorts first.  So compare to the appropriate integer.  I *think* you should add `< 0` to the condition.  Sorry, I don't have an editor available atm.  Should be: `if (values[left].CompareTo(values[mid]) < 0)`.  *I think*

Comment: @GiggyLapisar See [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah that works perfectly. Thank you so much. Now I'll just have to quickly read through it to truely understand how it works.